# Pseudo-inverse matrix different in Julia and Python

Tags: python, julia, matrix-inverse

I am trying to transcribe a python code in Julia. I have a matrix

```
test = [2.0 3.0 4.0
        3.0 4.0 5.0
        4.0 5.0 6.0]
```

I am computing the (Moore-Penrose) pseudo-inverse of a matrix in Python using `numpy.linalg.pinv` and the result is

```
[[-8.33333333e-01 -1.66666667e-01  5.00000000e-01]
 [-1.66666667e-01 -7.86535165e-17  1.66666667e-01]
 [ 5.00000000e-01  1.66666667e-01 -1.66666667e-01]]
```

while in Julia the result of `LinearAlgebra.pinv(test)` is

```
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.33333   -0.166667      1.0     
 -0.166667  -6.59195e-17   0.166667
  1.0        0.166667     -0.666667
```

I would like to ask if anybody knows why the results are different in the two cases and what I can do to have them match. So far I have tried `LinearAlgebra.pinv(test[1:3,1:3])`, and the result is also different for unknown reasons, but still doesn't match the Python output.

The above 'test' matrix was indeed a test case to simplify the code in a minimum working example, the actual code can be found below.

The full code in Python is:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n_bin = 8
A = 5.
sigma_G = 3.

G_temp = np.zeros((n_bin,n_bin))

for i in range(n_bin):
     for j in range(n_bin):
         G_temp[i,j] = A*np.exp(-(1/2)*((i-j)**2)/sigma_G**2)

G_matrix = np.matmul(G_temp,G_temp.T)
G_inv = np.linalg.pinv(G_matrix)
```

and the code in Julia is:

```
using LinearAlgebra
using Distributions  
using Base

n_bin = 8
A = 5. 
sigma_G = 3. 

G_temp = zeros(n_bin,n_bin)

for i = 1:n_bin
    for j = 1:n_bin
         G_temp[i,j] = A*exp(-(1/2)*((i-j)^2)/sigma_G^2)
    end
end

G_matrix = G_temp*transpose(G_temp)
G_inv = LinearAlgebra.pinv(G_matrix)
```

Comment: You built a completely different `test` matrix in Python. `print(test)` and see.

Comment: Hi @Ine, please don't paste code or output as images or links. That makes everything quite hard to follow. I have inlined the contents for now, please make sure it still matches.

Comment: Side note: if you find yourself writing `pinv(A) * x` any time, without really needing the pseudo inverse itself, use `A \ x` instead. That does the same thing more efficiently.

Comment: Your two code snippets, as they stand, give me exactly the same results in both languages (within float precision tolerance). What exactly is different when you run it?

Comment: The results of the two snippets are both in my initial post.

Answer (score 6):

I can not reproduce:

```
julia> using PyCall; np = pyimport("numpy");

julia> test = [2. 3. 4.; 3. 4. 5.; 4. 5. 6.]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 2.0  3.0  4.0
 3.0  4.0  5.0
 4.0  5.0  6.0

julia> pinv(test)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.33333   -0.166667      1.0
 -0.166667  -4.16334e-17   0.166667
  1.0        0.166667     -0.666667

julia> using PyCall; np = pyimport("numpy");

julia> pinv(test) ≈ np.linalg.pinv(test)
true
```

Note that I get a different pseudo inverse using `numpy` compared to what you posted.

```
>>> test = [[2.,3.,4.],[3.,4.,5.],[4.,5.,6.]]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.linalg.pinv(test)
array([[ -1.33333333e+00,  -1.66666667e-01,   1.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.66666667e-01,  -2.42861287e-17,   1.66666667e-01],
       [  1.00000000e+00,   1.66666667e-01,  -6.66666667e-01]])
```

**UPDATE:**

The numpy output you posted corresponds to the pseudo inverse of the  following slightly different matrix:

```
julia> test2 = [0. 1. 2.; 1. 2. 3.; 2. 3. 4.]
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.0  1.0  2.0
 1.0  2.0  3.0
 2.0  3.0  4.0

julia> pinv(test2)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -0.833333  -0.166667      0.5
 -0.166667  -7.63278e-17   0.166667
  0.5        0.166667     -0.166667
```

This is likely a matrix construction mistake on the python side. Note that `range(3)` in python does **not** correspond to `1:3` in Julia, but `0:2` as python starts counting with zero rather than one.

**UPDATE2:**

Since you have updated the OP, let me extend my answer. As pointed out above, `range(x)` in python corresponds to `0:x-1` in Julia. At the same time, array indexing in python starts at 0 while in Julia it starts with 1. Hence, assuming the python code produces the "correct" (expected) result, your Julia code should be as follows:

```
using LinearAlgebra
# dropped Base and Distributions here since you don't need them.

n_bin = 8
A = 5. 
sigma_G = 3. 

G_temp = zeros(n_bin,n_bin)

for i = 1:n_bin
    for j = 1:n_bin
         G_temp[i,j] = A*exp(-(1/2)*(((i-1)-(j-1))^2)/sigma_G^2) # note the (i-1) and (j-1) here!
    end
end

G_matrix = G_temp*transpose(G_temp)
G_inv = pinv(G_matrix)
```

Note that the loop variables `i` and `j`, which are used for indexing `G_temp` go from `1` to `n_bin` (and not `0` to `n_bin-1` as in python). We compensate for this difference by substracting 1 from both `i` and `j` in the expression on the r.h.s. of the assignment (in your particular case this doesn't matter because the shifts compensate each other). Then, the `G_matrix` is the same in Python and Julia and produces (roughly) the same `pinv`.

Comment: Our Julia outputs match, so apparently the numpy result doesn't. Could you please post your output for np.linalg.pinv(test) instead of checking if they match? Thanks!

Comment: They agree, so it is precisely the same. See my updated post for the "python shell output".

Comment: I used a loop to assign values in both cases, so as to avoid any definition problems.

for i in 1:3
   for j in 1:3
     test[i,j]= i + j 
   end
end 

 Sorry for the unformatted output

Comment: I posted the full python shell code. Do you get something different?

Comment: Yes, I included that in the initial post. See my updated post for the full shell code.

Comment: `range(3)` in python is `0:2` in Julia not `1:3`. I'll update my post.

Comment: Has my answer resolved your issue? If yes, you might consider indicating this to others by making it the accepted answer.

Comment: Even when the two matrices are the same initially, the problem persists.

Comment: In this case, could you please post the full code that you execute? Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: I added the actual code, not the test case with the matrix named 'test' as presented initially. I apologise if that causes any confusion.

Comment: Again, the issue is that `range(x)` in python is `0:x-1` in Julia. See UPDATE2 in my answer.

Comment: I believe I have cleary pointed out the issue. The rest is up to you...

Comment: Excuse me I was confused, I meant that I am getting the same G_matrix in both cases, despite the bug that you pointed out.